# Dealing with PULL in REXX

Tags: rexx

I am new to REXX and am stuck with the following issue:

I am writing a simplified panel that reads in a user id as well as a dataset name, and validates the latter.

```
/* REXX */                                                         
/**************************************************************/   
/* Simulation of panel that takes in user input */                 
say "Please enter your ID"                                         
pull id                                                            
say "Welcome" id || ". Please enter a dataset name."               
pull dsname                                                                                                             
say  "Validating " dsname "..."
```

However, while the id is output correctly the dsname (dataset) is not. It does not show up in the "Validating " dsname output.

```
 Please enter your ID                       
 **user**                                        
 Welcome USER. Please enter a dataset name. 
 *** **data**    
 Validating   ... /* Should be "Validating data..."*/
```

---

Is there something special about PULL that I am not addressing which is causing the omission in the output?

Comment: You say you're writing a panel - if it's an ISPF panel, you don't use Pull.  Have you tried TRACE I ?

Comment: Agreed - this is not a panel, it's just a REXX EXEC that prompts for arguments. To write a panel to achieve the same, you'll need to delve into ISPF dialog development...

Answer (score 1):

when you get the '***' prompt, you have to hit 'Enter' first - don't type your next input on that line. It's TSO's way of telling you that it needs to clear the screen...

```
 Please enter your ID                            
**user** <press enter>                                        
 Welcome **USER**. Please enter a dataset name.  
 *** <press enter>  
<screen clears>                                           
**data** <press enter>                
 Validating  **DATA** ...
 *** <press enter>
```